# Will Apple charge me for using the Push Notification Service?

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I have an Apple id, and I am building an application in which I am using Apple Push Notification Service, but I am a little confused about that.

Is there any charges for doing this process from Apple?
Is there any limit that it can run on specific number of Devices in which my app is installed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple will never charge you for using its Push Notification services. It's free and you can send notifications to any number of devices you want/have to.

Answer (score 1):

If u have apple id its free of cost and no limit of number of devices if app in production mode. If u have any problem with setting push notifications see this link, it might help u-
http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services

Answer (score 0):

Yes Its Free of Cost.No need to Spend Money